# MySQL Can't create new tempfile

Tags: mysql

If anyone is an X-Cart 4 user, or has experience, I am experiencing an issue with the table xcart_variants. It keeps getting "corrupted" or something. It's giving an error Table './elements_xcart/xcart_variants' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed

When I try to REPAIR TABLE xcart_variants I get the following error 
Can't create new tempfile:

Please help!

Comment: Look in the mysql error log. I'd suspect the temporary directory doesn't have any space or doesn't  have the required permission settings to create a file. After you recover, recommend changing to using innodb.

Comment: This does not really sound like a programming task, more like a DBA task (how to recover / repair a corrupted table). You may get a lot more help at SO's DBA sister site.

Comment: Try InnoDB engine.